# understanding docker run --attach option

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm a newbie with Docker and I'm pretty stuck at the how the `--attach` option works with `docker run`.

I would say that I've somehow understood the following command, as far as I understood with the `-it` Docker creates a pseudo-tty where the `/bin/bash` command is executed and the stdin and stdout of my local terminal is linked to the pseudo-tty.

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@d5e3551114ca:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

What I do not understand is the meaning of the following commands:

- In this case I see no output on my local terminal, but in the docker logs I can see that the keystrokes are intercepted and executed

```
docker run --rm --attach stdin -i ubuntu /bin/bash
```

- Here the container is started and stopped immediatelly

```
docker run --rm --attach stdin ubuntu /bin/bash
```

- Here the container is started but keystrokes are not intercepted nor the output is shown

```
docker run --rm --attach stdin -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

- Here I can see the output but keystrokes are not intercepted

```
$ docker run --rm --attach stdout -t ubuntu /bin/bash
root@b47a46abdf34:/# ls
```

Comment: I usually use the `-it` option, as in `--interactive` and `--tty`. More commonly, `docker run -it --rm container bash` to get a shell and have the container properly cleaned up after use.

Comment: Yes, I understand It. But what about "--attach"? What should I use It for?

Comment: Never had any occasion to use it, so don't know.